# Which characters could this person be reasonably dressed as?

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification

At a Harry Potter event last weekend, there was a woman dressed in a way depicted in the image below:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/5kCyw]

Does anyone have any suggestion concerning who she could be dressed as?

My first guess was McGonagall due to the green, but then I realized the wand doesn't match the one portrayed in the movies! McGonagall's wand has a tip which is both not pointy and not brown. Thanks to the helpful pointer from Harry Johnston, we know that this doesn't rule out Mcgonagall since (it seems) the books don't portray the appearance of her wand.

Comment: Is this a suitable question for the site? There's no definitive way to know who this woman was dressing up as without asking her, I would suggest.

Comment: @TheDarkLord That's a fair point! I've edited the title of the post to reflect my understanding of your comment. Unfortunately, I don't know the person in the image, so I can't ask them.

Comment: I don't think the books say anything that specific about McGonagall's wand, are you sure the costume was specifically based on the movies?  Also, unless this was a professional actor I don't know that they'd necessarily care about the details of the wand (and perhaps not even then).

Comment: @HarryJohnston - Her (old) Pottermore writing gave wand details. I doubt anyone making a costume would care though.

Comment: Do you know that she was dressed as a specific character? Don't people go to this sort of event dressed as generic witches and wizards?

Comment: @MissMonicaE That's a really good point! I'm not sure.

Comment: It's probably meant as a generic fancy-dress robe. It looks like the cut/construction was based on academic gowns and choir robes (which have a lot in common).

Comment: This question seems highly opinion-based to me. Like has been said by other commenters: only way to know for sure would be to ask her. Anything else is guesswork. It could, for all we now, be an original character created by her.

Answer (score 5):

## Possibly Dumbledore.

Dumbledore has a few outfits similar to that. It's not an exact match, but it does look close, and Dumbledore was the first one I thought of when I saw the costume. He wears similar colors, and it seems like it could be a variant on them. Dumbledore is often shown in outfits with similar colors, and similarly shaped collars.

He has a few similar outfits in that sort of color and style, but probably the closest to that specific costume is this one from the Half-Blood Prince movie.

[image]

Though he has at least two other outfits that also look like they could be the inspiration for this costume.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Construction-wise, those are not at all similar, actually. Dumbledore's outer robes have a wide, folded-back collar/lapels, while the cosplay outfit has a separate hood with triangular bits hanging down.

Comment: @Martha Yes, but it seemed like the closest match to Dumbledore's outfits than anything else, if it's supposed to be a recognizable character. In addition, it can be difficult sometimes to make an outfit exactly the same way as the character's, especially when it's a fairly complex one.

Comment: While not *impossible* I doubt that a woman without even a fake beard would be trying to pass off as Dumbledore.

Comment: @Bellatrix - difficult indeed! My daughter made Hermione's Yule Ball gown and spent about 6 months on it, and she made Clara Oswald's 1860's something [outfit](http://www.gotceleb.com/wp-content/uploads/celebrities/jenna-louise/coleman-at-dr-who-the-snowmen-promos/Jenna-Louise%20Coleman%20-%20Dr%20Who%20The%20Snowmen%20Promo%20-03-560x839.jpg) (Doctor Who) and spent almost a year on that!

Comment: @Skooba If she's a gender-bent Dumbledore, she wouldn't need a beard.